# 502 Bad Gateway Error on my AWS EC2 Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Good Afternoon,
I've been hosting my website on my AWS EC2 server for a couple of months now and its been working great. However, my website suddenly stopped working and gave me a **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.2** Error a few days ago.

The console log says this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

**I have tried:**

- Reboot EC2 instance
- Add a load balancer

Neither of these things helped. Does anyone know whats going on and how I can fix this? my website is http://thewildwear.com/ if you want to see the error message

Comment: EC2 is just a virtual machine; it's a program running on it that serves a website. What service on that machine is actually serving the website? Is it Nginx itself, or is Nginx acting as a reversee proxy? How does the website work - is it static, or is it PHP, NodeJS, etc? How is it configured? What do the error logs say?

Comment: Its running on a Ubuntu VM and my website files are stored in /var/www/*my files*. The website uses the html pages with embedded javascript and a separate php file to connect to my rds database. The console log says this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Comment: Not the log in the browser, the log on the server, where the error is occurring.

Comment: If I click on my instance--> instance settings --> get system log. It shows the log but no errors.

Comment: AWS console is useful for troubleshooting the instance, but again, and EC2 instance is just a virtual computer. Your issue is the software running on that computer. You'll need to log in and check the error logs for your server.

Comment: When I go to /var/log/nginx/error.log it shows this as the newest error - 2019/09/05 18:01:02 [crit] 991#991: *46 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.223.223.8, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "thewildwear.com"

Comment: That's the error you'll need to troubleshoot then - you might want to just delete this question and create a new question for that error tagged [php] so you can get better help with it.